# Is it true ZF can't prove there is a choice function on the Turing degrees?

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations, axiom-of-choice, descriptive-set-theory, large-cardinals

It is possible to show there is no Borel choice function on the Turing degrees. In fact we can even prove there is no Turing invariant Borel injection from $2^\omega$ to $2^\omega$, which sort of says that there is no injection from the Turing degrees into $2^\omega$. The proof relies on the measurability of Borel functions.

Now using some strong large cardinal-like axioms such as "every set is determined", one can show that there is no choice function *at all* on the Turing degrees. With much lower large cardinal assumptions, Solovay built a model of ZF in which every set is measurable. I'm not entirely sure, but it is probably the case that there is never a choice function on the Turing degrees in such models.

My question is : has anyone succeeded in building a model of ZF in which there is no choice function on the Turing degrees (or maybe on simpler equivalence relations, such as being equal almost everywhere), without using large cardinal assumptions ? or maybe such a thing known to be impossible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easy solution for the $E_0$ relation, i.e. equality mod finite.

Start with your favourite model, say $L$. Next add $\omega_1$ Cohen reals, and consider the permutations that modify each coordinate by "bit flipping" on finitely many natural numbers, independently on each coordinate. Finally, take the filter of subgroups given by countable support (i.e. on a countable set of coordinates we are guaranteed to not change anything).

It is now easy to show that in the symmetric extension:

1. $\sf ZF$ holds, and for good measure so does $\sf DC$.
2. The set of $E_0$-classes of the Cohen reals exists, i.e. $([r_\alpha]\mid\alpha<\omega_1)$, where $r_\alpha$ is the Cohen real.
3. There is no choice function from that set. Therefore no choice function from $2^\omega/E_0$.

Doing something similar with Turing degrees is trickier, I'm guessing, since those are more complicated than just equivalence mod finite, but it's not unthinkable (I suppose something along the lines of bit flipping on a computable set might work, but I never really grokked Turing degrees to the level I can just throw it out there with certainty).

Comment: Why doesn't the same argument work for Turing degrees? Fliping a bit lands you in the same Turing degree but produces a different real.

Comment: In general, $HOD(\mathbb{R})$ or $L(\mathbb{R})$ after adding $\omega_1$-many Cohen reals, is a model in which many such sets do not exist ($E_0$ transversals, Hamel bases, ultrafilters,...)

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest something like that. But decided to just play it safe and be explicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason I thought it should have been more complicated. If I now want everything to be measurable in the model, is it known to be doable without the use of large cardinal ?

Comment: @Archimondain: Shelah proved that if all sets are Lebesgue measurable and ZF + DC holds, then there is an inaccessible cardinal in $L$. Without DC you can have all sets Borel, but there is no way to develop measure theory, because the continuum is a countable union of countable sets (or some other similar disaster).

Comment: By the way, @Jonathan, the problem with this argument for Turing degrees is that there may very well be a representative which is *not* a finite modification of any of the Cohen reals. And it is certainly not true that the name of any real is moved only on finitely many points by the permutations.

Comment: @AsafKaragila We may assume that some condition already decides the computable function $e$ that maps one of the Cohen reals to its representative. Then since $e$ is continuous and as long as $e$ is not constant (modulo the finite part of the Cohen real that is already decided), we can modify finitely many bits of the real to get a different value. If  $e$ is constant, then swapping indices of the Cohen reals, plus the fact that mutual Cohens are not in the same Turing degree should do the trick. That should work, right?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, but why must a choice function be computable or continuous in any kind of way?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It doesn't need to be. But for a fixed real $r$ its representative is something that is computable from $r$. That's just part of the definition of Turing degree.

Comment: @Jonathan: Ah, that's what you meant. Yes, that seems like it should work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila By the way, even without using the particular structure of Turing degrees, for any name for a new real, we can change its evaluation by a finitary permutation of the Cohen reals. So all we need for the argument is an equivalence relation that contains $E_0$, and so that a Cohen real cannot have a ground model representative.

Comment: @Jonathan: That can't be right, consider the indiscrete equivalence relation. Certainly contains $E_0$, very easy to come up with a representative. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but there is representative already in the ground model.

Comment: @Jonathan: Fine, $x\sim y$ iff $\{x,y\}$ is in the ground model. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Unfortunately, I don't really understand your suggestion. What is the equivalence class of a Cohen real?

Comment: @Jonathan: Sorry, I messed that one up. $x\sim y$ if and only $x\in L\leftrightarrow y\in L$. (Replace $L$ by the ground model as necessary.)

Comment: Oh right, I see! I meant that in some sort of absolute way, when we add a Cohen real it will not have a GM representative (or in our specific case $c_\alpha$ has no representative in $V[\langle c_\beta : \beta \neq \alpha \rangle]$). Sorry, it was not very precise. I was thinking e.g. about countable Borel equivalence relations, where this is implied :)